# "pkd" process on El Capitan

Tags: macos

I just upgraded to OS X 10.11.2 (El Cap), and overall it seems to be working OK.

One strange thing: there's a "pkd" process which is taking ~150% CPU, all the time, even though I'm not doing anything.

(At first I thought it might have something to do with Spotlight reindexing or something, but 12 hours later it's still going.)

What is it?  Can I stop it?

Comment: Still a problem in 2018 with High Sierra. I wonder if corporate nannyware is to blame? This happens on my work computer. (I see it taking 99–100% CPU.)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The manpage says:

```
NAME
 pkd -- management and supervision daemon for plug-in services

SYNOPSIS
 pkd [-v]

DESCRIPTION
 pkd manages plug-ins for the PlugInKit subsystem. It is a classic launch
 agent managed by launchd.
```

Sounds pretty safe to kill it off, by opening a terminal and running:

```
launchctl stop com.apple.pluginkit.pkd
```

It should restart itself whenever it's required (possibly immediately).

Comment: I tried what seemed like a safer approach: `launchctl stop com.apple.pluginkit.pkd && launchctl start com.apple.pluginkit.pkd`.  My CPU usage went down a lot, and everything seems fine still.

Comment: I've found that running `App Tamer` and setting it to a 1% processor limitation is a safer and more easily monitorable solution vs altering things permanently.

Comment: It just restarts directly after killing it off, and returns with CPU usage of >100% with me. There has to be a better fix for this than just killing it off? Edit: I just figured out I'm running Cold Turkey, which might be the culprit. Can't kill that program until 15:30, so will try it out at that time.

Comment: I have the same issue, and `App Tamer` does not help. As soon as `pkd` is running, the whole system becomes unusable. How can identify the root application that is responsible for starting `pkd`?

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled all plug-ins to my Safari and that cured the problem.......very annoying process

Comment: Please could you edit your answer to mention which Safari plug-ins you had. This may help others better isolate the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Roboform plug-in with Safari, you might be having a known issue with CPU usage that can be fixed only by removing it.

More info:
https://discussions.apple.com/message/30212342#message30212342

Answer (score 0):

I killed Tunnelblick and Karabiner-Elements, then force-quit `pkd` in Activity Monitor, then restarted Tunnelblick and Karabiner-Elements. Fixed the problem.

Just killing `pkd` alone did not.